# Apache Directives Ordering: Global, Pre-VHost, or in Directory blocks

Tags: debian, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, rewrite

I'm setting up my first virtual server from scratch (provider name omitted but it's a 'droplet'). I've been using WHM for a while and I feel I'm fairly familiar with it.

Specifically, it's a Debian 8 machine, running Apache 2.4 (it uses `apache.conf` not `httpd.conf`)

Anyway, I'm having a hard time figuring out where to put what I consider global directives (they should apply to every site) that are available in every context.

Trivial examples would be setting a default charset or enabling `mod_deflate` to activate gzip.

More specifically, I have written rewrite rules to deal with unwanted referrers (spam referrers, but I don't need advice on that I am very familiar with the issue).

Here's essentially what I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  Options FollowSymlinks
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (badreferer1\..*) [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (crappy-referer2\..*) [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (webiste-i-hate3\..*) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm pretty sure my RegEx is correct (I want to redirect all protocols, all sub-domains, and all TLDs containing those strings).

It's my understanding these rules would work if added to each vhost directive block but that seems awfully redundant.

I'd be fine applying these rules globally but adding them towards the top of my `apache.conf` isn't working

Do I need to wrap them in a `<Directory>` block?

Could I put them in `<Directory />`?

All my sites are in `/var/www/html`, do I need to apply these rules in the `<Directory /var/www/html>`?

What am I missing (not in terms of code as this fragment is incomplete, but in terms of ordering directives and knowing where to put them)?

I'd like to keep my `.conf` file as concise as possible and avoid using `.htaccess` (and not `AllowOverrides` for perfromance reasons) so I'm trying to figure this out how to get this working in `apache.conf` (putting them in a file that is called via include is acceptable as there are already several in use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to rewrite rules, those are allowed in the main server config, but they don't effect VirtualHosts. [Somewhat hidden in the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) it is mentioned somewhat casually:

> Note that rewrite configurations are **not inherited** by virtual hosts. This means that you need to have a `RewriteEngine on` directive **for each virtual host** in which you wish to use rewrite rules.

So a universal set of rules in an include file as part of each VirtualHost seems the way forward.

In general though: The manual lists for [every directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/quickreference.html) 
where it is allowed, which is always one or more of:

- **server config**
  This means that the directive may be used in the server configuration files (e.g., httpd.conf), but not within any `<VirtualHost>` or `<Directory>` containers. It is not allowed in .htaccess files at all.
- **virtual host**
  This context means that the directive may appear inside `<VirtualHost>` containers in the server configuration files.
- **directory**
  A directive marked as being valid in this context may be used inside `<Directory>, <Location>, <Files>, <If>,` and `<Proxy>` containers in the server configuration files, subject to the restrictions outlined in Configuration Sections.
- **.htaccess**
  If a directive is valid in this context, it means that it can appear inside per-directory .htaccess files. It may not be processed, though depending upon the overrides currently active.

Directives in the the main server config apply to the whole server,
directives within a `<VirtualHost>` apply only to that virtual host
and there is a whole chapter on how all sections tie together: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/sections.html

Comment: I wish they highlighted that line as you did in the docs, would have saved me a lot of time. So I see that note in the `RewriteEngine` section  you linked to but I don't see that stipulation in `RewriteCond` or `RewriteRule`, does that mean I can keep those in a block above my vhost blocks and only add `RewriteEngine on` to each vhost or does all of it need to be in the `Include` for each vhost? Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know :) But feel free to experiment, test and share the results with us!